# How do I list Nth matches in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

On MS XLS I can do some aggregate or leech off a structured reference, but I really don't know how to find the Nth result based on word match on Google Sheets.

I have huge columns - name, role. I need to pull out the first 10 people off any given role. Obviously, this can be done by sorting and filtering, but due to the non-stop changes to the list, it's better to get it by a formula that I can copy 10 times to get 10 matches.

Here is how to find the last match in case anyone is interested:

```
=LOOKUP("keyword",C1:C100,D1:D100)  

(a word you match, search range, result range)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(C5:D, "select D where C = '"&$C5&"'",0), 3, 1)
```

or:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(C5:D, "select D where C = '"&"west"&"'",0), 3, 1)
```

to get first 10 matches

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(C5:D, "select D where C = '"&$C5&"'",0), 10, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Fancy stuff. I could always getaway way with not needing arrays in MS excel :)

Comment: how do I pull out just specific Nth results? For instance just the 5th?

Comment: like this: `=INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(C5:D; "select D where C = '"&"west"&"'";0); 5; 1); 5)`